# Reference of STL vector that contains references to objects generates error in C++. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, stl, reference

Why can't I have a reference to std::vector that contains references to objects? The following code generates a compile error in Visual C++ 2010:

```
void Map::Filter( Object::Type type, std::vector<Object&>& list )
{
  for ( register int y = 0; y < MAP_H; y++ )
    for ( register int x = 0; x < MAP_W; x++ ) {
      if ( under[y][x].GetType() == type )
        list.push_back(under[y][x]);
      if ( above[y][x].GetType() == type )
        list.push_back(above[y][x]);
    }
}
```

Summarized compile error:

```
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory(137): error C2528: 'pointer' : pointer to reference is illegal
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(421) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::allocator<_Ty>' being compiled
```

I solved the problem by switching from a "vector of references to objects" to a "vector of pointers to objects". I just can't understand why I can't have a reference to a vector of references.

Comment: References must be *initialized* at decl-time; pointers do not.

Comment: Why `std::vector<Object&>` instead of simple `std::vector<Object>`?

Comment: The short answer is "because the standard says so." If you really want, you could create a vector of `reference_wrapper`

Comment: std::vector<Object> would be a vector of copies of objects?

Comment: Yes, vector<object> will copy (or move, in C++11) objects into/out of the vector. If you want to avoid the objects themselves being copied/moved, you might consider a vector of shared_ptr or unique_ptr (for only a couple possible alternatives).

Comment: Also `register` doesn't seem right here. Just trust your compiler.

Comment: @LihO I thought I could speed up things a bit. Where would 'register' seem right then?

Comment: @FernandoAiresCastello: Just don't try to *"speed up"* anything before you really need to.

Comment: I'd say `register` is completely obsolete.

Comment: In case you're interested in the portion(s) of the standard that deal with reference rules, See C++11 § 8.3.2, particularly paragraph 5: *"There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references, and no pointers to references. The declaration of a reference shall contain an initializer (8.5.3) except when the declaration contains an explicit extern specifier (7.1.1), is a class member (9.2) declaration within a class definition, or is the declaration of a parameter or a return type (8.3.5); see 3.1. A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function."*

Comment: @WhozCraig: That's not a comment, but actually a correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard Containers use an Allocator to allocate memory and construct and destruct elements. The Allocator requirements are specified for an Allocator class `X` which is responsible for allocating objects of type `T`. The type `T` is specified as "any non-const, non-reference object type" (Table 27). So there simply are no requirements for an Allocator of reference objects. This means trying to create a container of reference type will lead you straight to undefined behaviour.

Table 27 is found in §17.6.3.5 Allocator requirements:

[image]

An alternative is to use a vector of `std::reference_wrapper` and `push_back` your elements with:

```
list.push_back(std::ref(under[y][x]));
```

Another alternative is using raw pointers or perhaps using an implementation of the [World's Dumbest Smart Pointer](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3514.pdf).

Also, I recommend not calling your vector `list` - there is a `std::list` container type. What is it a list of? `cats`? `people`? `bananas`?

Comment: OK I'm using raw pointers now, it works fine, I was just curious about why I didn't work with references and I had no knowledge of the standard. What I have there is a container for "Object" objects, and I call it a "list" even though it's a vector because calling it a "list" looks more natural and for me it makes no difference what it's called. I don't use std::list in my program anywhere.